# Mongoimport shell query in php code

Tags: php, mongodb, shell, codeigniter, mongoimport

How to execute mongoimport / mongoexport (shell) query using PHP code? I have tried using exec(), shell_exec(), system(), passthru() commands. None of these worked for executing such query code from program level.

My code:

```
$result = exec('mongoimport --host hostname --db mycoll
--collection mycoll --type json --file /home/xxx/filename.json --jsonArray 2>&1  ',$outputArray);  
print_r($outputArray);
```

Note: Checked for error_reporting by adding **2>&1** to the command. Got these errors:

```
mongoimport: /opt/lampp/lib/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.11' not found (required by mongoimport)
mongoimport: /opt/lampp/lib/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.9' not found (required by mongoimport)
mongoimport: /opt/lampp/lib/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.15' not found (required by mongoimport)
mongoimport: /opt/lampp/lib/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.15' not found (required by /usr/lib/libboost_thread.so.1.46.1)
mongoimport: /opt/lampp/lib/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.9' not found (required by /usr/lib/libboost_program_options.so.1.46.1)
mongoimport: /opt/lampp/lib/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.11' not found (required by /usr/lib/libboost_program_options.so.1.46.1)
```

The same query if executed in terminal imports json data to my mongo collection. How to fix these version issues inorder to import this query through php code?

Comment: php has a write permission to this folder?

Comment: Yes checked for the permission to /home/xxx folder

Comment: What is the output of print_r statement?

Comment: It shows null value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just tested your code example above on ubuntu 14, PHP 7, [MongoDB v3.4](https://www.mongodb.com/mongodb-3.4)(for [mongoimport](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongoimport/)) and it runs without an issue.

Based on the output that you posted, it looks like PHP is executing `mongoimport` using the environment of `/opt/lampp/lib/libstdc++.so.6`. This file version may be too old and does not define `GLIBCXX_3.4.x` version.

> The same query if executed in terminal imports json data to my mongo collection.

This is most likely because you're using a different `libstdc++.so.6`. for example: `/usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6` which is likely to meet the GLIBCXX criteria.

You can find out which `libstdc++` is being used on the shell by running below command:

```
/sbin/ldconfig -p | grep stdc++
```

Possible solutions:

1. Remove `/opt/lampp/lib/libstdc++.so.6` and use your working `libstdc++.so.6`
2. Un-set LD_LIBRARY_PATH in PHP so that the execution sources your system installed `libstdc++`.
3. If your installation of LAMPP is old, uninstall and re-install to reset/update `libstdc++`.

An alternative, is to not call external script `mongoimport`. Instead to write PHP code to read the `JSON` file and use [MongoDB PHP library](https://docs.mongodb.com/php-library/master/) to insert documents. See [Tutorials: Insert Documents](https://docs.mongodb.com/php-library/master/tutorial/crud/#insert-documents). 
As an example, you can iterate the read the json file as below:

```
$data = fopen("/home/xxx/filename.json", "r");
while(($line = fgets($data)) !== false) {
    $json = json_decode($line, true);
    print_r($json); 
    //Add logic to insert document to MongoDB.
}
fclose($data);
```

Comment: Hi i have tried your possible solutions in Ubuntu 12.04 and it worked.. Thank you.. :-)

Comment: Wan, if your json is not too small, say 50k records, don't you expect the `mongoimport` to be way faster than using the MongoDB PHP library?

Comment: @gen, I wouldn't say definitely faster. Depends on your PHP code, i.e. you can do multithread bulk import. It is easier to call `mongoimport` and take advantage of the multi workers with the workers option `numInsertionWorkers`. Depends whether you want to call an executable and handle the return code, or an internal code with controlled logging/handling.